# What is the path for font in mapfish print module for windows in config.yaml?

Tags: geoserver, mapfish

The following path is for linux:

```
fonts:
  - /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans
```

What is the path in order to call font type from windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it working using:

```
fonts:
    -  'C:\Geoserver_data_dir\printing\arial.ttf'
```